# design pattern for long and dynamic arguments to pass into function

Tags: python, design-patterns

I need to pass a long arguments configuration each time I call

```
model = create_model(var1, var2, ..., var20)
```

as I have 20 arguments for the function, where some of them are fixed every time I call it and some of them are dynamic according to the calling scenarios. Now my current solution is to create a config class for the fixed arguments and then I only need to change the dynamic ones each time I call `create_model`

```
config = Config(var1, ..., var15)
model = create_model(config, var15, ..., var20)
```

Is there more efficient method or more pythonic method to apply ?

Comment: Use named arguments and pass a dictionary with `**args`

Comment: Take a look at `functools.partial`.

Comment: If you will have multiple models at once, consider making `create_model` a method of a class whose `__init__` method takes the 15 or so fixed arguments.

Comment: @chepner seems reasonable to convert to class method. Also I wonder if my current design is an efficient way and what could be the potential issue ?

Comment: not sure, but can builder design pattern be the way out?

Comment: Factory, factory method, builder etc. could be considered